# Cannot access Django admin on production

Tags: django, nginx

My setup: Backend Django, Frontend React

I have a website dockerized on production in following configuration:
one container for serving static files, reverse proxy using nginx
second for django backend.

On development (without docker I am just running django admin using default configuration localhost:8000/admin), no issue here.
The problem is on production. I think I have to add a location to /admin, otherwise it will be handled by frontend which I assume won't work with django admin.

This is my full nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <website_url>;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name <website_url>;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<website_url>/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<website_url>/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

     location /auth {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

    location @proxy_api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass   http://backend:8000;
    }

     location /admin/ {
        alias /app/backend/server/django_static/;
    }
    
    location /django_static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/backend/server/django_static/;
    }   
    

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/media/;
    }
}
```

I tried to first add a redirect path in my react router:

```
 `{ path: "admin/*", element: <Navigate to="/admin/" /> },`
```

In result I have just a blank page.

Next, I've added a following rule in my nginx to handle /admin path:

```
`location /admin/ {
        alias /app/backend/server/django_static/;
    }`
```

When I enter my website/admin/ I receive error 403 forbidden from nginx.